Is conduit required for a small gap between the wall and a hard-wired appliance?
I have a Stelpro Uniwatt wall heater 240V which needs to be hardwired. The problem is that it has a bracket for mounting on drywall which means the heater has a gap of approximately 1/2 inch off the drywall. Do I need to put the 14/2 cable in a conduit for 1/2 inch?
Model: Stelpro Uniwatt 20000W  # UHC2002WCW

Pictures with the heater not mounted and mounted might make it easier for people to understand what you are describing. It would help if the bracket is mounted to the wall even when the heater is not. It also might help if you told us your code jurisdiction. Canada? US? Which state or province?

Most of these heaters are fed from the back. If this is the case, the additionl protection of the conduit wouldn't be necessary. However, you'll still need a proper connector for the NM cable. One connector that's commonly used is a NM two screw cable clamp. See picture below from Amazon who I'm not affiliated with in any way. This connector will take up the 1/2 inch you were worried about so you'll sleep better at night.

